# Office 365 OAuth without redirect

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, office365

I have been attempting to use office 365's [javascript client library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-contacts-tasks-client-library) to get contacts from office 365. The library opens a popup to get the users office 365 details and returns the access token in a query string in the new window. Is there a way to get this information in the original window?

This is the code which causes the problem (from msdn example):

```
var authContext;
var authToken; // for use with creating an outlookClient later.
authContext = new O365Auth.Context();
authContext.getIdToken("https://outlook.office365.com/")
   .then((function (token) {
       authToken = token;
       // The auth token also carries additional information. For example:    
       userName = token.givenName + " " + token.familyName;
   }).bind(this), function (reason) {
       console.log('Failed to login. Error = ' + reason.message);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither the auth code nor the id token are the same as the access token. To get the access token:

```
authToken.getAccessToken('https://outlook.office365.com').then(function (accessToken) {
  // do something with accessToken, e.g. use as bearer token in REST call
}, errorFunction);
```

If you are going to use the wrapper API you can instead use authToken.getAccessTokenFn() and pass this to the constructor for your Office client.

```
var outlookClient = new Microsoft.OutlookServices.Client('https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0', token.getAccessTokenFn('https://outlook.office365.com/'));
```